# How to properly concatenate multiple variables in asp.net core ViewData[] object of a view

Tags: razor, asp.net-core-mvc, viewdata

Up at top of my view:

```
@{
ViewData["Title"] = @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.SETitle);
ViewData["Description"] = @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.SEDescription);

ViewData["canonical"] = String.Concat("https://example.com/", Html.DisplayFor(model => model.CategoryURL), "/", Html.DisplayFor(model => model.URLSlug));
```

}

This renders in the browser like so:

```
<link rel="canonical" href="https://example.com/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.StringHtmlContent/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.StringHtmlContent">
```

I am using a standard asp.net core template. And it seems like this will always occur if you are concatenating multiple variables together for a ViewData[] string. What do I need to change about my syntax to get this actual values to pass through and render in my browser?

Comment: What are the values of `CategoryURL` and `URLSlug`? And why you assigning the result to a `VIewData` property (are you then using the values in your Layout)? And why are you using `Html.DisplayFor()` instead of just `@Model.CategoryURL` etc?

Comment: Strings. Yes, the layout. You are right, I should be using `@Model` instead of Html.DisplayFor. That was the problem. I tried `@model`and it was invalid but obviously that has to be capitalized. Please add your answer and I will mark as solved. Thanks. Knew it had to be simple.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All your properties appear to be type of `string` so there is no need to use `Html.DisplayFor()` (but if you do, then it needs to be `@Html.DisplayFor()` - note the leading `@` so the result of the method is output).

Instead you can just use `@Model.CategoryURL` and `@Model.URLSlug`.

And if `https://example.com/` is your site, then you should be doing this using the `Url.Action()` method to generate the correct relative url without hard-coding the site name.

In addition, you have commented that these values are being used in your layout, in which case, consider using base view model containing those properties and set them in the controller method so that the Layout uses `@model yourBaseViewModel`, and each view that uses that layout inherits from your base view model

Comment: Thanks for your other recommendations.